# View successful logins to my Google Compute Engine instance

Tags: logging, ssh, google-compute-engine

I've got a GCE instance running Ubuntu. The Serial Console informs me that it's under constant brute-force attack via SSH from a few IPs. I'd really like to be able to see a log of all *successful* SSH logins to my instance so that if someone gets in, I'll at least know about it.

How can I view such a log?

Comment: Yo down-voter and close-voters: Why?

Comment: SuperUser or ServerFault might be more appropriate forums for this question, since it's not strictly programming-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saving your logs locally, you can either use the `last` command, as Lennert mentions, or look in `/var/log/auth` ([on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles#Authorization_Log)), `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/audit/audit.log` ([RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/chap-Security_Guide-General_Principles_of_Information_Security.html)).

Note that if you're saving your logs locally, it's possible for an attacker who achieves root to remove the logs of their access -- many organizations use remote syslog to avoid this, but if you're running a single server, it may not be worthwhile.

[SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/186020/how-can-i-log-ssh-access-attempts-and-keep-track-of-what-ssh-users-end-up-doing) has some more information about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The linux "last" command will show you all successful logins. If you want to view the failed logins you can use the "lastb" command.

Comment: GCE's Ubuntu image seems to have `/var/log/wtmp`, which `last` relies on, disabled.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? I have several 14.04 instances running in GCE and last is working as intended